# Response.Redirect("Login.aspx") causing timeout/page not found error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

using VS 2010 and ASP.NET 4. The following code when executed times out and produces a 'page not found error.' Login.aspx does however exist.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This "Login.aspx" relative path is saying that it should be within the same folder as the page you are directing from (the above code). If it indeed does exist and you're getting this error, it is probably in another folder, perhaps a parent folder? If you give us more info on your file hierarchy, we could help you get the right path

Comment: Login.aspx is located in the same folder as Default.aspx, which contained the redirect. Both are located in the root folder of the web app.

Comment: If I redirect to "Ad_Help.aspx" it works. It's located in the same folder! (huh?!)

Answer (score 1):

try using a relative or absolute URL because the described behaviour sounds like the browser tries to load the page from a location it doesn't exist...

Comment: I understand that but I think it is perhaps "too relative" from the POV of the browser receiving it.

Comment: OK got it. There was another redirect in the login that directed back to default.aspx *blush* Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the headers in firebug. What is the server sending back to the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Try telling it to redirect to the root of the web app

```
Response.redirect("~/login.aspx");
```